# Calling subprocess when another one is still running, can it be?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have python code that run subprocess command `dtncpd` for receiving all file that coming in.

`subprocess.call(["dtncpd","/home/dtn2"], cwd="/home/dtn2/dtn-2.9.0/apps/", shell="false")`

`dtncpd` must be running everytime. But i want to run another subprocess too without interupting the `dtncpd` subprocess in one file python.

Another subprocess like:

```
topik = subprocess.Popen(["ls","-l"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd="/home/dtn2/")
    komp, err = topik.communicate()
    kompserver = komp.split()
    cek = len(kompserver)
```

The two process above is not related to each other and have different purposes.

The currently result is program never reach the second subprocess. It's still waiting on first subprocess only.

How can i fix it?

Comment: FYI, `shell="false"` is doing the opposite of what you want. A non-empty string is "truthy", so you effectively passed `shell=True`. If you want to avoid the shell, don't pass the `shell` argument at all, or pass `shell=False` (the actual boolean value, not a string).

Comment: Most of the functions of the basic posix commands, such as `ls`, can be done more efficiently directly using functions in the `os` module. Here you can just use `listdir` without a subprocess.

Answer (score 3):

`subprocess.call` is a utility function that runs and then waits for the process before it returns. If you want the process to run in the background without Python waiting for it to complete, you need to use the raw `Popen` constructor:

```
subprocess.Popen(["dtncpd", "/home/dtn2"], cwd="/home/dtn2/dtn-2.9.0/apps/")
```

I removed the `shell="false"` bit because [as I noted in the comments, it does the opposite of what you intend.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400147/calling-subprocess-when-another-one-is-still-running-can-it-be#comment58502830_35400147)

Note that your second subprocess is almost certainly the wrong way to go about this. Between `os.listdir` and `os.stat` (or on Python 3.5, `os.scandir` alone), you can get the same information as `ls -l` provides more efficiently than using a subprocess.

Answer (score 3):

That's what [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) does: it *waits* until the child process completes.

You can fix it by running the first command with `Popen()`:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["dtncpd","/home/dtn2"], cwd="/home/dtn2/dtn-2.9.0/apps/")
```

Since you do not need to communicate with this process (using `subprocess.call()` does not collect child output), this should be fine.

Later, once the second command has terminated, you can call `p1.wait()` to wait for the child to exit - assuming that it ever will. That will prevent zombie `dtncpd` processes being created.

This might be somewhat naive in that the first command looks like it might be a daemon process. If that is the case, and you are simply wanting to start the `dtncpd` daemon, you need to make sure that `dtncpd` does in fact daemonise. I am unfamiliar with `dtncpd`, there might be a config setting or command line argument that you need to supply in order to have it daemonise properly.

Comment: yes, `dtncpd` is like daemon. i try to use Popen in first command but still the second process cant be reach.

Comment: @RembulanMoon: daemon or not, `Popen()` should return, not block. I mentioned daemonisation because `subprocess.call()` should return if the child were to daemonise. But `Popen()` shouldn't block. What other code are you executing after the first `Popen()`?

Comment: Can you add a debug statement after each call to Popen() (or call()) so you can see which Popen(), if any, is blocking?

Comment: Thank you, i try to stopping Popen that running everytime with killing the pid. So now it doesnt block another Popen.